# Case Insensitive javascript replace regex taking account word boundary

Tags: javascript

I am writing the replace function in javascript taking account into word boundary

```
blog = blog.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp("\\b" + wordList[i].toLowerCase() + "\\b", 'g'), "value to replace");
```

Now this is a **CASE SESITIVE** Replace i want to make it **CASE INSENSITIVE**.

How can i accomplish this?

Though for Case Insensitive there is **\I** but i dont know know how to fit it in my code

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `i` with `g` in the `flags` argument of the [`new RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax). Like so:

```
new RegExp("\\b" + wordList[i].toLowerCase() + "\\b", 'gi')
```

At that point, you should be able to remove all the `String.toLowerCase` calls:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + wordList[i] + "\\b", 'gi');
blog = blog.replace(re, 'value to replace');
```

**N.B.** you may need to [escape the value of `worldList\[i\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) so that your code does not accidentally try to create a malformed regexp.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to read my edit about escaping, if you didn't see it already.

Answer (score 2):

change your `'g'` to `'gi'` -- the "g" means "global", the "i" means "case insensitive":

```
..., 'gi'), "value...
```