# Replicating the Ctrl+F behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, search, text

I want  to hightlight all the occurance of a word in the document. For this, I have written the following code:

```
function highlight_search_param() {
    // get the search_param from location.search
    filters = location.search.substr(1).split('&')
    search_param = ''
    for (i in filters) {
        param = filters[i].split('=')
        if (param[0] == 'q') {
            search_param = param[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (search_param == '') return True
    alert(search_param)

    // convert into many possible cases
   title_search_param = search_param = search_param[0].toUpperCase() +              search_param.substring(1)
          $('.summary-block').contents().find(':contains("'+search_param+'"),:contains("'+search_param.toLowerCase()+'"),:contains("'+title_search_param+'"),:contains("'+search_param.toUpperCase()+'")').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(search_param)>=0) {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(search_param, "<span class='highlight'>" + search_param +"</span>"));
    }



})
}
```

Now, since I am over writing the `text()`, span appears as a text. (obviously)

If I over write the `html()`, there are chances that there are other elements (siblings of that text node) with might get erased.

Note.

- there are lots of `$('.summary-block`) in the page
- the search should be **case insensitive** but the replacement should remain with the case intact
- there can be more than one occurrence of the `search_param` inside the `summary block`

basically, I am looking for something similar to the `ctrl+F` behavior of browsers

(FIDDLE)[http://jsfiddle.net/bYhxs/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like:

```
$(".summary-block").each(function () {
  $(this).html(function (index, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(
      search_param, 
      "<span style='color:green;'>" + search_param + "</span>");
  });

});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzJz/4/)

This is ALOT less code and it only looks at the text of the element, not the Html.

Edit: As per comments, I have updated this to work with more than one `.summary-block` element.

**EDIT**: As per your new edit. Please see the above fiddle. Basically, you create a RegExp object and specify a pattern to replace instead.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(search_param, 'gi');
//..
replace(pattern, "<span style='color:green;'>" + search_param +"</span>")
..//
```

See this post for more information:

[Case Insensitive javascript replace regex taking account word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651892/case-insensitive-javascript-replace-regex-taking-account-word-boundary)

Worth noting, you don't need all that contains checking now. Just use this final code:

```
var search_param = "seaRching";
var pattern = new RegExp(search_param, 'gi');

$(".summary-block").each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
       pattern, "<span class='highlight'>" + search_param +"</span>"
       )
   );

});
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYhxs/1/)

Comment: yes, but if there are other elements like `<div class="summary-block">This is searching for something
    <span>sdsadaS</span>
    <div>sadas</div>` those get replaced tooo

Comment: This would have problems if there is more than one element with the '.summary-block' class. Or is it a given that there's only one such element?

Comment: @MichaelGeary - Good point, thanks. I have updated my answer to suit and updated the fiddle with a new example.

Comment: @MichaelGeary , @webnoob , is `replace` case insensitive? because I replaced your code in the `if` part of my code. is working fine. but would you suggest me to remove the `$('.summary-block').contents().find()`.. portions also?

Comment: You don't need to call `html()` twice, just use: `$(this).html(function (index, oldHTML) { return oldHTML.replace(search_param, "<span style='color:green;'>" + search_param + "</span>"); });` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzJz/3/)).

Comment: @webnoob , i have updated my question, i need the replace to be **case insensitive**

Comment: @Rhea - Can you update your original post with the latest code you are using please? In my mind at the moment you just need to use `toLowerCase()` on the string when doing the `contains` check but I will let you know once your code has been updated.

Comment: @webnoob , i have updated my question, I want **ALL** the searching to be highlighted

Comment: @Rhea - Post edited. The fiddle example and code in the post now works regardless of case.